# Is this SIGABRT crash in android app caused by xamarin log handler?

Tags: android, xamarin.forms

I have an app which can run for multiple hours, doing various datalogging and computation and then suddenly it just closes without warning. Sometimes it can run for a few hours and other times for 10+ hours. I see no pattern to the crashes.

If relevant, the app starts a service to let it run in the background, and I do not believe I have ever seen it crash, when I was using it in the foreground, but this may simply be due to random chance, as it runs for so long before crashing, and I am not interacting continuously with it for multiple hours.

The only thing I have been able to extract from the log is this Fatal signal 6 (SIGABRT), code -1 (SI_QUEUE) with a very short back trace, seeming to indicate an error inside monoRuntime

There is no errors, related to my app, ahead of this.
I understand that this error indicates that the os think the main thread is unresponsive, which I have no reason to believe it is (due to the app itself), as I never see it being lagging, when I interact with the app and heavily use async methods everywhere possible.

What confuses me is that it seems that the trace for this crash only points at logging in monoRuntime.

Does this ring a bell for anyone, or does anyone have suggestions for how to get further insights?

```
12-04 07:23:11.987 21879 19265 F libc    : Fatal signal 6 (SIGABRT), code -1 (SI_QUEUE) in tid 19265 (SGen worker), pid 21879 (nleaf.APPNAME)
12-04 07:23:12.183 19931 19931 F DEBUG   : *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** ***
12-04 07:23:12.183 19931 19931 F DEBUG   : Build fingerprint: 'OnePlus/OnePlus8T_EEA/OnePlus8T:11/RP1A.201005.001/2110091916:user/release-keys'
12-04 07:23:12.183 19931 19931 F DEBUG   : Revision: '0'
12-04 07:23:12.183 19931 19931 F DEBUG   : ABI: 'arm64'
12-04 07:23:12.184 19931 19931 F DEBUG   : Timestamp: 2021-12-04 07:23:12+0100
12-04 07:23:12.185 19931 19931 F DEBUG   : pid: 21879, tid: 19265, name: SGen worker  >>> com.COMPANY.APPNAME <<<
12-04 07:23:12.185 19931 19931 F DEBUG   : uid: 10440
12-04 07:23:12.185 19931 19931 F DEBUG   : signal 6 (SIGABRT), code -1 (SI_QUEUE), fault addr --------
12-04 07:23:12.185 19931 19931 F DEBUG   :     x0  0000000000000000  x1  0000000000004b41  x2  0000000000000006  x3  000000772818a370
12-04 07:23:12.185 19931 19931 F DEBUG   :     x4  0000007a89e68000  x5  0000007a89e68000  x6  0000007a89e68000  x7  0000000002cad50c
12-04 07:23:12.185 19931 19931 F DEBUG   :     x8  00000000000000f0  x9  b9888c8ec21c48ae  x10 0000000000000000  x11 ffffffc0fffffbdf
12-04 07:23:12.185 19931 19931 F DEBUG   :     x12 0000000000000001  x13 000000000000008d  x14 003a9dba64477d63  x15 00003a355394f5f7
12-04 07:23:12.185 19931 19931 F DEBUG   :     x16 0000007a83478c80  x17 0000007a8345abb0  x18 000000000000000e  x19 0000000000005577
12-04 07:23:12.185 19931 19931 F DEBUG   :     x20 0000000000004b41  x21 00000000ffffffff  x22 0000000000000028  x23 000000770596ee08
12-04 07:23:12.185 19931 19931 F DEBUG   :     x24 000000772818aaa7  x25 0000000000000001  x26 0000000000000000  x27 0000000000000000
12-04 07:23:12.185 19931 19931 F DEBUG   :     x28 000000772818aa90  x29 000000772818a3f0
12-04 07:23:12.185 19931 19931 F DEBUG   :     lr  0000007a8340e420  sp  000000772818a350  pc  0000007a8340e44c  pst 0000000000001000
12-04 07:23:12.195 19931 19931 F DEBUG   : backtrace:
12-04 07:23:12.195 19931 19931 F DEBUG   :       #00 pc 000000000004e44c  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib64/bionic/libc.so (abort+164) (BuildId: 3b0dd94de78a8a796f793e81b7adfbd0)
12-04 07:23:12.195 19931 19931 F DEBUG   :       #01 pc 0000000000027f30  /data/app/~~0xhpW0BWzTQwaVrnyYNfug==/com.COMPANY.APPNAME-G2Ho6l9aHu86OPfvc2Bt-Q==/lib/arm64/libmonodroid.so (xamarin::android::internal::MonodroidRuntime::mono_log_handler(char const*, char const*, char const*, int, void*)+144) (BuildId: 233985597f330fc4c0655ab2526301e997f54e94)
12-04 07:23:12.195 19931 19931 F DEBUG   :       #02 pc 000000000028b6f8  /data/app/~~0xhpW0BWzTQwaVrnyYNfug==/com.COMPANY.APPNAME-G2Ho6l9aHu86OPfvc2Bt-Q==/lib/arm64/libmonosgen-2.0.so (monoeg_g_logv_nofree+192)
```

Comment: Do other apps have this problem?

Comment: Not that I am aware. If it was not clear, this app is my own code. I have no other apps running like mine does.

Comment: You can create a new demo and try again.

Comment: I am not sure I see what you mean by "a new demo"..?

Comment: What I want to know is will this problem occur in your other apps?

Comment: I just ran into this same problem. Our latest update was quite minor, barely more than changing android target version from API 29 -> API 30

Comment: [This](https://github.com/xamarin/xamarin-android/issues/6546) looks somewhat similar.

Comment: your backtrace is not any deeper ? there probably is more to this. I am the original poster of the issue link by @FelixZY and my current (limited) undestanding of my issue (might be a different one though) is that there is a corner case race condition happening when stressing the garbage collector from multiple thread and there is a bridge taking a lot of time (special garbage collector mechanism for android)

if you can reproduce easily, my workaround was to add a file with build action 'AndroidEnvironment' and following content: `MONO_GC_PARAMS=bridge-implementation=new,mode=throughput`

Comment: In my app, changing the bridge implementation is probably just a workaround to make the bug less likely to happen but i do not think it addressed the root cause of the issue.
One problem that arose from this implementation change was a severe performance degradation on low/middle - end (and even sometimes high-end) android devices so this is why i added the mode=throughput to make the garbage collector collect less often.

Comment: My backtrace is even more shallow  but for the same files. Unfortunately, I have not been able to reproduce locally yet - I only have info from production crash reports.

Comment: @Tomtix trying out your workaround. Currently i see the issue on 6.12.0.162. Anybody knows a newer released or earlier version that works with .NET 5 ?

Comment: Any updates on this? @JoeTaicoon did you found the root cause of issue?

Comment: Unfortunately no, and the comments in here did not seem to lead anywhere.